# ajax calendar control Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajax Calendar control in asp.net web application. Everything works fine in all browsers except IE10.
Whenever I click on calendar control to select date in IE 10 then the following error is shown to me in debugging mode.
I am using AjaxToolkit version 1.0

JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 
Value must be an integer.
Parameter name: x
Actual value was 338.30999755859375.

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a bug in IE10, So you can render the page in IE9 standards. You need to add following tags inside `head` tags on html code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

[Click here](http://code.gishan.net/code/solution-to-ie10-ajax-problem/) for more references.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ScriptMode="Release"` on ToolkitScriptManager

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false" ScriptMode="Release"
EnablePartialRendering="True" >
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```